# setting up cocos2d CCBitmapFontAtlas for arabic font android

Tags: android, bitmap, cocos2d-android, bitmap-fonts, cclabelttf

i am stuck at getting an arabic fnt and png file(bitmap font style ) which i have created with Hiero bitmap font tool to work with my cocos2d android game.
i am replacing this line

```
"CCBitmapFontAtlas selectgame = CCBitmapFontAtlas.bitmapFontAtlas ( "english string", "englishfont.fnt");"
```

to

```
CCBitmapFontAtlas selectgame = CCBitmapFontAtlas.bitmapFontAtlas ( "arabic string", "arabicCreated.fnt");
```

the first one works ok, the english font's fnt and png files are in assets which works smoothly but when i try an arabic string with the arabic bitmap font i 've generated it simply shows nothing instead of the text in the app.
nothing appears in the log also. because it 's a bitmap i cant print it to the log i guess.
i tried with other bitmap font generator but no luck
any help would be greatly appreciated,
tnx alot

Comment: try giving full specified path of your .fnt file. Between can you share the error which you are getting?

Comment: added to the question, tnx